# Argument of type 'WalletConnectProvider' is not assignable to parameter of type 'provider'

Tags: web3js, wallets, walletconnect

I am using an example from the WalletConnect documentation:

```
public async connectWalletConnect() {
    //  Create WalletConnect Provider
    const provider = new WalletConnectProvider({
      infuraId: '5234234fdsfewr34234324fdfs',
    });
    //  Enable session (triggers QR Code modal)
    await provider.enable();
    this.web3 = new Web3(provider);
  }
```

But I got this error *inside new Web3(provider)*

```
Argument of type 'WalletConnectProvider' is not assignable to parameter of type 'provider'.
  Type 'WalletConnectProvider' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Help, please)

Answer (score 3):

This issue is due to typescripts typechecking, one hack to bypass it is to typecast provder as `<any>provider` in `this.web3 = new Web3(<any>provider)`